# Mixed results when querying for customers on keyup

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

My JS frontend queries customers by keypress with min 3 chars to enter before axios makes the query ie: `/api/customers/q?=kev`, `/api/customers/q?=kevi`, `/api/customers/q?=kevin`

I never seem to get the expected results. If paste the full name in the input and query for "kevin" in one go, kevin would return from the api. Here's my query:

```php
// Other variables are not shown ie $postcode

$customers =  $this->with(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])->whereRaw("lower(FirstName) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(Surname) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(lower(FirstName), ' ', lower(Surname)) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(CompanyName) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(EmailAddress) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhere(function($customers) use ($postcode)  {
                if(isset($postcode)) {
                    $postcode = strtolower($postcode);
                    $customers->whereRaw("lower(PostCode) = '${postcode}'");
                }
            })
            ->where('Foo_ID', $fooId)
            ->paginate(20);
```

I expect that when the user types in "kevin", letter for letter, the customer kevin should be returned because "kevin" is in the database and should I paste "kevin" in the input, kevin returns.

Currently I have to use `onBlur` in the JS which would pass the complete name to the API but I do not want that.

Comment: If I'm correct you should group your orWhereRaw in a closure. From the documentation: "If you need to group an "or" condition within parentheses, you may pass a Closure as the first argument to the orWhere method" https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: In addition to @Rolf's comment, I'll advice that you start with a simple query. Check first with first name. If you get a result then you can query for other fields in addition to that.

Comment: @Rolf That's it, that works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment above, I've added the working answer for @Sylar.

If I'm correct you should group your orWhereRaw in a closure. From the documentation: "If you need to group an "or" condition within parentheses, you may pass a Closure as the first argument to the orWhere method":[laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses)

```php
$customers = $this->with(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
    ->where(function ($query) use ($postcode) {
        $query
            ->whereRaw("lower(FirstName) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(Surname) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(lower(FirstName), ' ', lower(Surname)) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(CompanyName) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhereRaw("lower(EmailAddress) like '${query}'")
            ->orWhere(function($customers) use ($postcode)  {
                if(isset($postcode)) {
                    $postcode = strtolower($postcode);
                    $customers->whereRaw("lower(PostCode) = '${postcode}'");
                }
            });
    })
    ->where('Foo_ID', $fooId)
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Please show him how you would do it, stackoverflow is about fixing code, not just linking to documentation :)

Comment: @mrhn I've added a code sample. Thanks for the suggestion!